# Is this possible to verify zero interactions with OCMock?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock

Using OCMock, we can verify if an interaction with mock objects happen, like:

```
id mock = OCMClassMock([SomeClass class]);
OCMStub([mock someMethod]).andReturn(myValue);

/* run code under test */

OCMVerify([mock someMethod]);
```

But is this possible to verify if there's no interaction with mock object, similar to the Mockito#verifyZeroInteractions()?

Comment: The one way to go around this problem is using strict mock (i.e. when there's no expectations, it means zero interactions), but the downside is that you have to set expectation for all mock interactions, which is cumbersome for many other tests.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to define a strict mock:

```
id mockObject = OCMStrictClassMock([SomeObject class]);
```

Do not define any expectation for the unwanted method, and finish test with:

```
OCMVerifyAll(mockObject);
```

It the method was called, the test will fail.

Comment: Yes, using strict mock is an option (as I also mentioned in the comment of the question). Just FYI: you don't need to have OCMVerifyAll(mockObject), as strict mock will throw if there's no expectation.